# Invariants in chemistry used for model selection

Tags: molecules, theoretical-chemistry, molecular-structure

What invariants related to geometrical structures that describe molecular geometry are used in chemistry?

Explanation: Here, [Electronic model with highest prediction rate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14671/)…, one can learn about electronic models. Now, I want to learn which invariants are used in all major models used (and why).

Definition of invariant: [Invariants in chemistry used for model selection](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14701/invariants-in-chemistry-used-for-model-selection)

Example of invariants in physics of ideal gas (invariance of the geometry of ideal gas with respect to Legendre transformations): http://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0222v1.pdf

Comment: This question could use some context and elaboration.

Comment: trb456, I am interested to learn about low-level molecular interaction. Here, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14671/electronic-model-with-highest-prediction-rate, one can learn about electronic models. Now, I want to learn which invariants are used in all major models used (and why).

Comment: What do you mean by **invariant**? Do you mean a constant, as in Planck's constant? Or do you mean a variable that is always included in the model? Or do you mean it in one of the senses outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant)?

Comment: I use the following definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)

Comment: Suddenly, this becomes an incredibly broad question. There are two reasons it will be hard to get a good answer here. First, most chemists aren't also mathematicians, and will have a hard time identifying things as mathematically invariant even if they use them regularly. Secondly, you can find things that are classified as invariant in almost any model in chemistry - from balanced equations to statistical mechanics to quantum matrix mechanics. If you can be more specific about what types of invariants and what types of systems you are thinking about, it would help narrow it down.

Comment: thomij, I am mostly interested in invariants related to geometrical structures that describe molecular geometry, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_geometry. In physics, one could mention e.g. invariance of the geometry of ideal gas with respect to Legendre transformations, see: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0222v1.pdf

Comment: In that case, maybe you could edit your question to focus on that? I believe that you might be talking about what quantum chemists would call symmetries in molecular orbitals.

Comment: thomij, I edited the question to make it more specific. Still, I would be interested to hear about other invariants, too.

Comment: various symmetry rules are widely used, mostly in the field of quantum chemistry to simplify calculation models and spectroscopy to select spectroscopic active state transitions.

Comment: Martin, I did what you suggested. Now, the question may be clear to non-mathematicians. I also added related links from the comments.

Comment: Just a general remark on the functionality of this site: Put an `@` in front of the name, to notify this person. See [help] for more.